# ccTouchesMoved in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cocos2d-x

Hello all I am new in COCOS2DX framework and trying to develop brick breaker game. i am following this demo [Brick breker game](http://www.raywenderlich.com/475/how-to-create-a-simple-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-tutorial-part-12) this tutorial is in cocos2d (iPhone). I code it in cocos2dx and got work correctly. but when i am implementing `ccTouchesMoved` method. My code compile and run properly but as i touch(click) screen it breck down and give error  violation ocures. My code is

```
void HelloWorld::ccTouchesMoved(CCSet* touches, CCEvent* event)
{
    if (_mouseJoint == NULL) return;

    CCTouch *myTouch = (CCTouch*)touches->anyObject();
    CCPoint location = myTouch->locationInView();
    location = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(location);
    b2Vec2 locationWorld = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);
    _mouseJoint->SetTarget(locationWorld);
}
```

How can i resolve this issue. Please guide me.

Comment: Your code doesn't check for null pointers.  Perhaps touches is null, perhaps myTouch is, or perhaps CCDirector::sharedDirector() returned NULL.

Comment: which line it break at? _mouseJoint->setTarget?

Comment: yes it is breaking at same line.

Comment: hello all i got solution i just commented if condition in `ccTouchesBegan(CCSet* touches, CCEvent* event)` method for checking mousejoint null or not. But i do not suppose its solution. would you please tell me how can we initialize mousejoint without null value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the demo that you provided, the following code initialized the mouseJoint

```
if (_paddleFixture->TestPoint(locationWorld)) {
    b2MouseJointDef md;
    md.bodyA = _groundBody;
    md.bodyB = _paddleBody;
    md.target = locationWorld;
    md.collideConnected = true;
    md.maxForce = 1000.0f * _paddleBody->GetMass();

    _mouseJoint = (b2MouseJoint *)_world->CreateJoint(&md);
    _paddleBody->SetAwake(true);
}
```

it is in ccTouchesBegan

Answer (score 3):

```
void ClassName::ccTouchesBegan(NSSet *touches, UIEvent* event )
{

      if (_mouseJoint != NULL) return;
      ...
}
```

May be you are not initializing _mouseJoint to NULL.

In the constructor of your class, initialize _mouseJoint = NULL;